# What button is represented by this symbol in phpstorm?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, key-bindings

I was fiddling around in PhpStrom's keymap, and was confused by the predefined key binding for `Hide active tool window` as I don't recognize the circle symbol with the tilted arrow. What button am I supposed to press?

[image: Keybinding for Hide active tool window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle/arrow symbol is for the escape key (and the up-arrow is shift).